# listing the window services from a remote server having authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
connection options=new connection options()

options.username="";

options.Password="";

options.Authority = "kerberos:xxxx.com";

string root = @"root\cimv2";

 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", "xxxxxx", root),options);

scope.connect();
```

the exception raised is "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

someone please help me figure this issue

Comment: Did you try the suggestions mentioned in the errormessage and if so, what were the results?

Comment: the results after trying them are : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: Does that code work when you put it in a console app and you run with your credentials on the webserver?

Comment: nope it doesn't,it shows up that the RPC is unavailable,don't know whether it's an issue with my machine or the server i am trying to access,could you please shed some light on which side the issue must be popping up??

Comment: I expect either a firewall (on either server or in between on the network) or the server you try to connect to doesn't have the appropriate service running but I don't recall  which service that is.

Comment: is it windows management instrumentation

Comment: It could be, not sure if that also handles the remote calls